# IMPORTXML comes back as blank

Tags: web-scraping

I'm trying to get the restaurant's address from a website using IMPORTXML.

When pulling the xpath the selected line (for the street) I get this information:

//*[@id="marmita-panel0-2"]/div/div[2]/p[2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCcEM.png)

The formula I write on the Google Sheets cell is =IMPORTXML("URL Address","//*[@id='marmita-panel0-2']/div/div[2]/p[2]") and returns blank.

Comment: Can you share the url, so that we can undestand the problem (may be this page is uilt by javascript, but contains a json)

Comment: this is the link 
https://www.ifood.com.br/delivery/santo-andre-sp/hamburgueria-sabor-amigo-parque-das-nacoes/1d270c55-1158-49a7-8df4-f369402a07e0

Answer (score 0):

The site is built in javascript on the client side, not the server side. Then you cannot retrieve the information using importxml. Hopefully the data is contained in a json inside the source. So try:

```
function info(){
  var url='https://www.ifood.com.br/delivery/santo-andre-sp/hamburgueria-sabor-amigo-parque-das-nacoes/1d270c55-1158-49a7-8df4-f369402a07e0'
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.split('<script type="application/ld+json">')[2].split('</script>')[0]
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  Logger.log(data.address.streetAddress)
  Logger.log(data.address.addressLocality)
}
```